# WebGL Texture read/write at the same time

Tags: textures, shader, webgl

I want to do some rendering with webGL shader but I need to read an array of data which was generated by the shader from previous frame. I'm doing this with using the shader to write to a texture and read that texture with the same shader. However, this doesn't work. The shader can read the texture from the last frame and write to the frame buffer perfectly but it just can't write to the texture again. I also tried to copy the texture to other image unit but it doesn't work either. I'm wondering if there's any restriction on the texture of webGL that you can't do read/write in the same shader? or I did something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Yi

Answer (score 7):

From Common mistakes in http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes :
"Normally, you should not sample a texture and render to that same texture at the same time. This would give you undefined behavior. It might work on some GPUs and with some driver version but not others."

Use instead two textures using the ping-pong approach (The following tutorial is OpenGL, but using the technique in WebGL should be straight forward):

http://www.mathematik.tu-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/oldstuff/HelloPingPong.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm wondering if webGL supports different color buffers. But I tried to copy the texture to two image units by using glBindTexture. So the shader reads texture from one unit and write to the other one, but however, it didn't work. Is there anyone knows if this is doable?

Comment: Not, it's not doable. You need to use the ping pong approach. Hre's a sample that reads from the texture it just wrote to http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/persistence/persistence.html and there's a video about it here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg#t=31m42s

Comment: Is this also valid for WebGPU? Should this approach also be used to ping-pong textures like we used to do with framebuffers with WebGL? Or is it ok with this new API to have a read-write framebuffer texture to read from and update to each frame (e.g.: ray tracer)?